# Resolving Dependencies when creating instance of class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, console-application, class-library

Note:  I do understand DI in the sense of asp.net core, where dependencies are "magically" (OK how I font know) injected into controllers.  But I need to achieve that in a console app.

I got a console app, which are to initialize and call methods on classes in a class library.
These classes have various dependencies which at the moment I got working from the constructor.

```
private readonly ISomeService _service;
public class DemoThing(ISomeService service)
{
    _service=service;
}
```

Setting up DI in one's console app is easy enough, and pass it to the instance of a class you are creating.

However I *need* to be able to do it the way it's done in MVC.

The "old" app I'm rewriting (not by me, so dont understand it fully) uses StructureMap to achieve this ;
`myisntance = ObjectFactory.GetInstance("someclass");` which gives one an instance of a class with all dependencies resolved.

Really hope this make sense and just need a push in the right direction (or advice on what to learn, I'm kinda new to this)

Comment: Not sure I understand why StructureMap isn't a starter for you. It's certainly more mature than `System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver`. You may be dealing with an old version of StructureMap - v4 instantiates a little differently than your example, e.g.: `var container = Container.For<YourApplicationRegistry>(); var myinstance = container.GetInstance<someclass>();`

Comment: I actually thought about if we should not stick to StructureMap.  But figured I'd try see if .net core dependency injection will work (so I can explain later why not to whoever ask)

Comment: Can you elaborate what it means to "be able to do it the way it's done in MVC"?